# Create a random number in android and save it to android database?

Tags: java, android, database, random

Still fairly new to android. I am trying to learn how to create a random number that has 12 characters, and each time a number is randomly created, it saves to the android database. Please any help with giving me an idea on how to do this would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Math.random();  
//Complete rnd float between 0 and 1 e.g.
//0.2558734951799192
//0.03857502479001995
//0.08562741500057713
//0.2329257841571789
//0.7471882261881438
```

or

```
Random rand = new Random();
int rndNumber = rand.nextInt(49);  
//Numbers between 0 and 48
```

--

So 12 digit random number can be done with both

```
float random = 100000000000 + Math.random() * 899999999999;
```

or

```
Random rand = new Random();
float rndNumber =100000000000 +  rand.nextFloat(899999999999)+1;
```

--

**Edited thx to Frizi**

Comment: your number has up to 12 chars, not exactly 12. The right solution is int rndNumber = 100000000000 + rand.nextInt(899999999999);

Comment: Yeah had too much ice cream to think about the whole details :D

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a general question so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You can use the [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class in java to generate your random numbers. For information on how to then store it to a database, chekcout this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).